# Outline for anchor should display only while tabbing through the page

Tags: html, css, outline

I have an anchor tag and I need to display the outline while tabbing through the page and should not shown while clicking on it. I have used the following code.

```css
a:focus {
  outline: blue dotted 2px;
  outline-offset: 5px!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tabindex="0">New link</a>
```

Is it possible to remove outline while clicking on  it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify all the possible states (default, active, focused) explicitly.
The state is both active and focused when clicked, but only focused (not active) when selected with the tab key.

```css
a, a:link, a:active, a:hover {
  outline: none;
}
a:focus:not(:active):not(:hover) {
  outline: blue dotted 2px;
  outline-offset: 5px!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tabindex="1">New link</a><br>
<a href="#" tabindex="2">Another link</a>
```

Comment: But still the outline is visible on click

Comment: How big a problem is that? Normally, links navigate away from the page as soon as they're clicked, so you wouldn't see it. Anyway, I've corrected it.

Comment: Actually I  have used anchor tags for an accordion and the link doesn't go to another page .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("outline", "none");
  });

  $("a").on('focus', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("outline", "blue dotted 2px");
  });

  $("a").on('blur', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("outline", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
a:focus {
  outline: blue dotted 2px;
  outline-offset: 5px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" tabindex="0">New link</a>
```